# Magento 2 paytm order conformation mail getting before payment

Tags: magento2, email, payment

Customer chooses to pay by Paytm -> Is redirected to Paytm gateway -> Magento IMMEDIATELY sends out an Order Confirmation Email to the customer, before he even completes the payment.

Customer shuts down browser without making payment because he thinks he paid already.
Magento says the order is processing so I (a seller) assume payment has been completed. But when I manually check the payment status in merchant.paytm.com - payment hasn't been made at all (customer closed browser after full page load).

How to set up Magento/Paytm extension, so that the Order confirmation is sent to customer AFTER he completes the payment?

Comment: Please share module source

Comment: iam using paytm latest payment getway code for magento 2.1.7
pls have look on this url for code https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Magento_Kit/tree/master/Magento_v2.x

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Did you fixed it?

Comment: no MR.Vinod kumar  still iam trying to resolve this issue .... please help me out on this

Comment: hi Amith what you want exactly total code or what

Comment: Did you checked there was commit just 5hrs before stating they have fixed the issue , maybe take a pull ?

Comment: HI MR.Vishwas Bhatnagar i dont know who fixed these issue no one didnt fixed these issue